# Change color of link on webview

Tags: android, webview, hyperlink

I'm getting html from the network and show in the webview.
in default my html has some  link that show in the webview with blue color.
How can I Change the color of this to the black ?

Comment: Why not use `css` or `<style>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add some custom CSS/ JS to do this.
Just create your own JS like :

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {
// Do some stuff like color change, add some CSS
})()");
```

Comment: call this after your webpage is loaded, and it will attach this JS to your content.

Comment: Duplicate question answer is better.